# Modx evolution HTTPS

Tags: modx, https, ssl

Mixed content при переходе на https.
В админке стоит https галочка.
В конфиге прописан siteurl с https.
Но все скрипты и файлы все равно выдаются через http. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

В `.htaccess` редирект с `http` на `https`
**1 способ**
`RewriteCond %{HTTP:SSL} !=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]`
**2 способ**
`RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`
**3 способ**
`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`
**4 способ**
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`
Пробуйте, один должен сработать. Всё зависит от настроек вашего сервера.
И, наверное, вы используете старый Modx Evo?
Сейчас это уже отдельная [Evolution CMS](https://github.com/evolution-cms/evolution)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема не в htacess, а mixed content по причине http base url, а вот как его поменять без понятия, да старая версия

Comment: Очистить кеш в админке. В `assets/cache` удалить, если таковые имеются, `siteCache.idx.php` `siteHostnames.php` `sitePublishing.idx.php`. Ещё способ. В base указать так `<base href="/" >` или вписать руками https. Но это уже крайний способ и не рекомендуемый.

Comment: Ничего не помогло из того:(

Comment: Если можно - ссылку на пациента